# Netbeans FrameView CenterScreen,ChangeSize

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am modifying a Java Desktop Application made using NetBeans 6.9.1 . No matter what i do i am unable to change the size of the main application neither can I centralise it.

Netbeans uses something called FrameView it extends JFrame . So no Jframe object is directly available

what i have tried already

```
this.getFrame().setLocationRelative(null);
this.getFrame().setSize(whatever,whatever);
```

above 2 dont work

neither can i find any option in GUI Builder

I have a feeling this question may have been asked but i have failed to find the correct answer

Comment: If FrameView extends JFrame, then isn't the FrameView the JFrame that is accessible? You say "So no Jframe object is directly available", but also "FrameView it extends JFrame". Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's likely that `FrameView` is make changes that are overriding your settings, either internally (have overridden those methods) or in time (changing it after you have set it)

Comment: @MadProgrammer there is an initComponent() method in the constructor . I have to tried to add the code after and before it but nothing works .  although if i use methods like setMinimunSize() and setTitle() they do work

Comment: @NESPowerGlove i meant u can get the jFrame object via this.getFrame()

Comment: Note: `this.getFrame().setLocationRelative(null); this.getFrame().setSize(whatever,whatever);` should be `this.getFrame().setSize(whatever,whatever); this.getFrame().setLocationRelative(null);` or better still `this.getFrame().pack(); this.getFrame().setLocationRelative(null);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson been there done that

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).  Base it on a `JFrame`.

Answer (score -1):

Alright with @MadProgrammers hint i have come up with the worst possible solution

Netbeans View File has a class (our application) which extends a FrameView(netbeans native class) . This class is instantiated in {}app.java file .. This class has a constructor which calls an initComponent() method . but over rides some properties after the constructor has finished (MadProgrammers) .. I was able to fix the issue by writing the following code just before the constructor ended the solution works every time but i have a feeling that stackoverflow is going to kill me :)

```
final JFrame f=this.getFrame();
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     try {
         Thread.sleep(200L);
         f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
   }
};
Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
thr1.start();
```

Comment: Negative rating :O .. why would that be ?